# Adicionando selected="selected" no input

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um loop em js com um `<select>` e `<option>`, preciso definir um `selected` para o `<option>`, porém como ele está no loop eu não posso acrescentar direto nesse `<option>`, tem alguma sugestão ou dica?

Segue o código:

```
var $html = "<select class='form-control' name='usuario' id='usuario'>";
for( var i in data ){
    var u = data[i];
    $html += '<option value="'+ u.login +'">' + u.login + '</option>';
}
$html += '</select>';
```

Comment: descreva melhor qual o campo ou condição do campo, q vc quer, pra que fique selecionado o campo

Comment: O option que o usuário selecionar, ele deve ficar com o atributo selected="selected"... Já tentei onclick no option mas não funciona.

Comment: não é no click que testa isso, é melhor testar com o onchange, vc pode usar jquery?  se puder, tem o seletor ':selected' conforme o link: http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Comment: Sim, posso usar Jquery...testei com change:

 $(document).on('change', 'select#usuario>option', function(){
  $('select#usuario>option').attr('selected',true);
 });

Comment: tenta assim:       $(document).on('change', 'select#usuario>option', function(){ $(this).attr('selected', 'selected'); });

Comment: Podes sim juntar `selected` dentro do loop. Como é que sabes qual é o `option` que deve estar marcado? existe algum padrão para isso? de onde sabes essa informação?

Comment: Se eu colocar o selected dentro do option, por estar dentro de um loop, todo s terá essa propriedade, e quando o usuário for escolher, independente da sua escolha, o valor sempre será o ultimo adicionado!

Comment: Primeiro verifique qual a opção ou opções devem estar marcadas, depois trate tais opções dentro do loop, usando uma condição com  `if... else`